# Build a HyperLink in a GridView in ASP.NET webforms - Eval not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview with a template field that has a HyperLink:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="12%" HeaderText="VER" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Ver" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>  
       <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Teste/Teste.aspx?rac=<%#Eval('idApontamento')%>" runat="server">TEXT</asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I am getting `The server tag is not well formed.` in the HyperLink line.

What should I do in order to directly build a querystring in a HyperLink ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Build your hyperlink like this:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Title"
  DataTextField="Some Text"
  DataNavigateUrlFields="idApontamento,CustomerID" 
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Admin/Teste/Teste.aspx?rac={0}&CustomerID={1}" />
```

Keep adding comma delimited values to the `DataNavigateUrlFields` property, and markup the `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` as you would `string.Format()`

Comment: And now.. how do I add more fields to the querystring as well ?

Comment: @MarceloRamires: I've updated the answer now regarding multiple fields.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can embed an expression like that, you have to pick to give it all text, or all binding expression.

Thankfully, you can contatonate string in a binding expression.  Try something like this:

NavigateUrl='<%# String.Concat("~/Admin/Teste/Teste.aspx?rac=", Eval("idApontamento")) %>'

Comment: NavigateUrl='<%# String.Concat("~/Admin/Teste/Teste.aspx?rac=", Eval("idApontamento")) %>'  
you were missing a ).

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra double-quote after the pound (#) symbol.  Does removing that help?